# Dynamic analysis of a robot pedestal

Tags: robotic-arm

I have to design a robot pedestal for a research project.The robot I choose is kuka KR 6 R700 6.In the datasheet is said all the forces/moments in worst case scenario.I did some FEA for the structure taking into the accountant these, but this is only static analysis.Von Mises stress is below YS of the material, SOF atleast 2 and deformation of 0.3mm.Also I found natural frequencies of the structure.What im concerned of, is if I should also simulate something regarding dynamic analysis.Like while is moving, if is enough stable not vibrate and change my points values.

Answer (score 1):

The static analysis should give you the worst-case position for the arm with regards to stress in the pedestal. The vibration modes of the pedestal may or may not be important for your application, but the thing I would be looking for in a dynamic analysis would be how the counter-torque compounds with the static loading. Don't forget to assume worst-case payload.

The robot in its worst-case kinematic orientation, with its worst-case payload, with its worst-case joint acceleration will give you the shear *and bending* information you need to evaluate the pedestal. Counter-torque should reduce stress in one half of the pedestal but make it worse in the other half, which may or may not cause you to exceed the yield strength of the base material.

Comment: When you talk about counter torque you mean a weight that compensate the robot worst case scenario ( payload, kinematics etc. ) ?

Comment: @AlexandruLebada - I mean the reactionary torque required to hold the base of the robot arm stationary when the robot arm moves. Every action has an equal and opposite reaction. You need to determine the reactionary force at the base of the arm and include that with your static loading.